# confusion using rjs for a link_to_remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs, link-to-remote

My application layout contains a navigation div, and a content div constructed as a partial. I want to use ajax so that whenever a person clicks on a link in the navigation div, the contents of that page renders in the content div without a refresh. I'm confused on how to properly do this...  any help for a rails noob??? thanks in advance~

application.html.erb

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/content'%>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
</body>
```

_header.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_remote "Home", :url => { :controller => "pages", :action => "home" } %>
```

_content.html.erb

```
<div id="content">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

pages_controller.rb

```
def home
  @title = "Home"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

home.rjs

```
page.replace_html :container, :partial => 'layouts/content'
```

Comment: FYI: `link_to_remote` is the Rails 2 way of doing this. As of Rails 3, `link_to ..., :remote => true` is used. Concerning your problem: Use the firebug plugin of Firefox and activate the console. There you can track your Ajax requests. If there is an error on the controller side, it is included in the response.

Comment: duddle this is EXTREMELY helpful I was trying to find that out for a while today.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming 'home.rjs' to 'home.js.rjs'. Everything else looks correct. What error are you getting?

Comment: hi thanks your your reply, the error I get:

try {
Element.update("container", "      <div id=\"content\">\n         \n        \n      </div>\n");
} catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('Element.update(\"container\", \"      <div id=\\\"content\\\">\\n         \\n        \\n      </div>\\n\");'); throw e }

Answer (score 0):

Try:

pages_controller.rb

```
def home
  @title = "Home"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
      render(:update) do |page|
        page.replace 'content', :partial => 'layouts/content'      
      end
    }
  end
end
```

You don't need extra rjs file. Also FYI, if you are saving @title to the DB, then you need to do @title.reload before respond_to to get latest data. The comment above about firebug is helpful.